# How to find out I am where for getting a Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

Consider the badge [**Sportsmanship**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship):

> Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.

How can I found out, where I am to getting this badge? How many answers I upvoted (where an answer of mine has a positive score) and how many remains to reach 100?